# Unpredictable behavior of a 74HC595, Q0 has no output and LED flickering

Tags: arduino-mega

Below is my schematics:

I am using a 74HC595 shift register and to test my connections, I have placed 8 LEDs to the output and shifted `0xFF` into the shift register (1111 1111), this should light up all the LEDs. However, Q1 to Q7 lit up, but Q0 didn't, it is very dim and flickering,
After doing some research and came across the decoupling capacitor and I have place a 10uF capacitor between the 5V and GND rail on the breadboard. However, the problem still persists, Am I missing something?
thanks!

Here is my code:

```
int data_pin = 8;
int latch_pin = 9;
int clock_pin = 10;
int reset_pin = 11;

void setup() {
  pinMode(latch_pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(data_pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clock_pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(reset_pin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  reset_SIPO_register();
  shift_SIPO(0xFF);
}

void reset_SIPO_register() {
  digitalWrite(reset_pin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(reset_pin, HIGH);
}

void shift_SIPO(byte sequence) {
  digitalWrite(latch_pin, LOW);
  shiftOut(data_pin, clock_pin, MSBFIRST, sequence);
  digitalWrite(latch_pin, HIGH);
}
```

[image]

Comment: the power rails are separated in the middle on those long breadboards

Comment: @Juraj I have several long breadboards, and the ones that are separated also have the red/blue lines interrupted in the middle to show. But Brendon: it's worth checking anyway.

Comment: It sounds like a loose connection. Try using a different part of the breadboard - the metal clips in the breadboard sometimes bend and fail causing bad connections.

Comment: So, green wire is 5V and is connected to the top red power rail and bottom blue... I wouldn't be surprised if you have LED cathodes on 5V, instead of 0V :D

Answer (score 0):

There is a maximum current the 74HC595 can deliver. Probably you are using more than this current.

See e.g. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/77841/how-much-current-can-my-74hc595-handle-on-each-output-pin

Some easy checks:

- Increase the resistor value so the total current is lowered
- Temporarily remove some LEDs, to see if the others behave like expected.
- Use other LEDs with a higher forward voltage to reduce the current.
- Changing the sketch to light one LED at a time to see if all outputs work.

Comment: I have tried removing 2 LEDs and Q0 still off,

Comment: How much current is going through the total LEDs? I read there is a max of 70 mA and if you put 7 x 20 mA = 140 mA it's double it can handle.

Comment: I haven’t done the analysis yet, but what makes me think that the current is okay is because sometimes the leds do light up but for some reason, sometimes it doesnt